# minimum operations required to make the longest character interval equal to K

Tags: java, c#, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I was asked this question in an contest.
Given a string containing only M and L, we can change any "M" to "L" or any "L" to "M". The objective of this function is to calculate the minimum number of changes we have to make in order to achieve the desired longest M-interval length K.
For example, given S = "MLMMLLM" and K = 3, the function should return 1. We can change the letter at position 4 (counting from 0) to obtain "MLMMMLM", in which the longest interval of letters "M" is exactly three characters long.

For another example, given S = "MLMMMLMMMM" and K = 2, the function should return 2. We can, for example, modify the letters at positions 2 and 7 to get the string "MLLMMLMLMM", which satisfies the desired property.

Here's what I have tried till now, but I am not getting correct output:
I am traversing the string and whenever longest char count exceeds K, I'm replacing M with L that point.

```
public static int solution(String S, int K) {

    StringBuilder Str = new StringBuilder(S);

    int longest=0;int minCount=0;
    for(int i=0;i<Str.length();i++){
        char curr=S.charAt(i);
        if(curr=='M'){
            longest=longest+1;
        if(longest>K){
           Str.setCharAt(i, 'L');
           minCount=minCount+1;
           }
        }

        if(curr=='L')
         longest=0;
 }
  if(longest < K){
        longest=0;int indexoflongest=0;minCount=0;
        for(int i=0;i<Str.length();i++){
            char curr=S.charAt(i);
            if(curr=='M'){
            longest=longest+1;
            indexoflongest=i;

            }
            if(curr=='L')
              longest=0;

        }
        Str.setCharAt(indexoflongest, 'M');
        minCount=minCount+1;



    }
  return minCount;
}
```

Comment: How are you dealing with other cases? can't there be a case where you need to replace L with M? where is that in the code?

Comment: I have edited the code to include that condition. But its not optimal.

Comment: what do you mean by optimal? what is the desired run time complexity? was it giving the wrong answer?

Comment: Clearly someone should add a solution in ML :)

Comment: @GaganDeep: Are you trying to cheat in this coding contest? https://app.codility.com/programmers/custom_challenge/cutting_complexity2018/ - Cutting Complexity - by Codility and ASML?

Comment: @The Ahn Nguyen this question was asked after I was done with contest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 parts to this algorithm as we want to get the longest character interval equal to K.

1. We already have a interval >= K so now we need to appropriately change some characters so we greedily change every (k + 1) th character and again start counting from 0.
2. Now if the interval was less than K I will need to run a sliding window over the array. While running this window I am basically considering converting all L's to M's in this window of length K. But this comes with a side effect of increasing the length of the interval as there could be K's outside so this variable (int nec) keeps track of that. So now I have to also consider converting the 2 possible M's outside the (K length) window to L's.

Here's the complete runnable code in C++. Have a good day.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
typedef vector <int> vi;
typedef pair<int, int> ii;



int change(string s, int k) {
    // handling interval >= k
    bool flag = false;
    int ans = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++) {
        if(s[i] == 'M') cnt++;
        else cnt = 0;
        if(cnt == k) flag = true;
        if(cnt > k) s[i] = 'L', ans++, cnt = 0;
    }
    if(flag) return ans;

    // handling max interval < k
    // If the interval is too big.
    if(k > s.size()) {
        cerr << "Can't do it.\n"; exit(0);
    }

    // Sliding window
    cnt = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++) {
        if(s[i] == 'L') cnt++;
    }
    ans = cnt + (s[k] == 'M'); // new edit
    int nec = 0; // new edit
    for(int i=k; i<s.size(); i++) {
        if(s[i-k] == 'L') cnt--;
        if(s[i] == 'L') cnt++;
        nec = 0;
        if(i-k != 0 && s[i-k-1] == 'M')
            nec++;
        if(i < s.size()-1 && s[i+1] == 'M')
            nec++;
        ans = min(ans, cnt + nec);
    }

    return ans;
}

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);
    freopen("in.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("out.txt", "w", stdout);

    string s;
    int k;

    cin >> s >> k;

    int ans = change(s, k);
    cout << ans << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks but its giving wrong answer.  for, change("MLMMMLMMMM", 2), its returning 3 but answer should be 2.  for, change("MLMMLLM", 3), its returning 3 but answer should be 1.

Comment: I made some changes. Can you confirm if its correct now.

Comment: Hmm, maybe wrong in this case?: change('MLMM', 3); got 1 but expected 2.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for the case. New changes.

Comment: I think you should add some explanation to your answer. Despite your solution meets the expectations of the contest.

Comment: Added the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int
process_data(const char *m, int k)
{
    int m_cnt = 0, c_cnt = 0;
    char ch;
    const char *st = m;
    int inc_cnt = -1;
    int dec_cnt = -1;

    while((ch = *m++) != 0) {
        if (m_cnt++ < k) {
            c_cnt += ch == 'M' ? 0 : 1;
            if ((m_cnt == k) && (
                    (inc_cnt == -1) || (inc_cnt > c_cnt))) {
                inc_cnt = c_cnt;
            }
        }
        else if (ch == 'M') {
            if (*st++ == 'M') {
                /*
                 * losing & gaining M carries no change provided
                 * there is atleast one L in the chunk. (c_cnt != 0)
                 * Else it implies stretch of Ms
                 */
                if (c_cnt <= 0) {
                    int t;

                    c_cnt--;

                    /*
                     * compute min inserts needed to brak the
                     * stretch to meet max of k.
                     */
                    t = (k - c_cnt) / (k+1);
                    dec_cnt += t;
                }
            }
            else {
                ASSERT(c_cnt > 0, "expect c_cnt(%d) > 0", c_cnt);
                ASSERT(inc_cnt != -1, "expect inc_cnt(%d) != -1", inc_cnt);
                /* Losing L and gaining M */
                if (--c_cnt < inc_cnt) {
                    inc_cnt = c_cnt;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (c_cnt <= 0) {
                /*
                 * take this as a first break and restart
                 * as any further addition of M should not
                 * happen. Ignore this L
                 */
                st = m;
                c_cnt = 0;
                m_cnt = 0;
            }
            else if (*st++ == 'M') {
                /* losing m & gaining l */
                c_cnt++;
            }
            else {
                // losing & gaining L; no change
            }
        }
    }
    return dec_cnt != -1 ? dec_cnt : inc_cnt;
}
```

Comment: Walk once. As you walk get the count of changes to make to meet at least K count of Ms in stretch and take the smallest as inc_cnt,

In the same walk, decrement the c_cnt, which will go negative when stretch of Ms cross K and for each stretch find the count of inserts required and sum it up.

Comment: I have a bug. I should count t only at the end of stretch,

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code:

```
int
process_data(const char *m, int k)
{
    int m_cnt = 0, c_cnt = 0;
    char ch;
    const char *st = m;
    int inc_cnt = -1;
    int dec_cnt = -1;

    while((ch = *m++) != 0) {
        if (m_cnt++ < k) {
            c_cnt += ch == 'M' ? 0 : 1;
            if ((m_cnt == k) && (
                    (inc_cnt == -1) || (inc_cnt > c_cnt))) {
                inc_cnt = c_cnt;
            }
        }
        else if (ch == 'M') {
            if (*st++ == 'M') {
                /*
                 * losing & gaining M carries no change provided
                 * there is atleast one L in the chunk. (c_cnt != 0)
                 * Else it implies stretch of Ms
                 */
                if (c_cnt <= 0) {
                    c_cnt--;
                }
            }
            else {
                ASSERT(c_cnt > 0, "expect c_cnt(%d) > 0", c_cnt);
                ASSERT(inc_cnt != -1, "expect inc_cnt(%d) != -1", inc_cnt);
                /* Losing L and gaining M */
                if (--c_cnt < inc_cnt) {
                    inc_cnt = c_cnt;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (c_cnt <= 0) {

                /*
                 * compute min inserts needed to brak the
                 * stretch to meet max of k.
                 */
                dec_cnt += (dec_cnt == -1 ? 1 : 0) + ((k - c_cnt) / (k+1));

                /*
                 * take this as a first break and restart
                 * as any further addition of M should not
                 * happen. Ignore this L
                 */
                st = m;
                c_cnt = 0;
                m_cnt = 0;
            }
            else if (*st++ == 'M') {
                /* losing m & gaining l */
                c_cnt++;
            }
            else {
                // losing & gaining L; no change
            }   
        }
    }
    if (c_cnt <= 0) {

        /*
         * compute min inserts needed to brak the
         * stretch to meet max of k.
         */
        dec_cnt += (dec_cnt == -1 ? 1 : 0) + ((k - c_cnt) / (k+1));
    }

    return dec_cnt != -1 ? dec_cnt : inc_cnt;
}
```